# Select multiple classes jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm pretty new to Jquery and writing a gallery with multiple pages and I have a problem with the Jquery selector.

I'm trying to select a `img` tag and a `a` tag, both tags have different class names and are in a `.portfolio-item` class.

What I've tried is

```
var countImages = $(".portfolio-item a img").length;
    console.log(countImages);
    var perPage = 8;
    $('.image, .edit-post-link').css('display', 'none');
    //$('.post-edit-link').css('display', 'none');
    //$('.slider').children().slice(0, perPage).css('display', 'block');
    $('.image, .edit-post-link').slice(0, perPage).fadeIn("fast");
    //$('.post-edit-link').slice(0, perPage).fadeIn("fast");
    function goTo(pageNumb){
        var startFrom = pageNumb * perPage;
        var endOn = startFrom + perPage;
        //$('.post-edit-link').fadeOut("fast").delay( 200 ).slice(startFrom, endOn).fadeIn("fast");
        $('.image, .edit-post-link').fadeOut("fast").delay( 200 ).slice(startFrom, endOn).fadeIn("fast");
    }
    var buttons = countImages/perPage;
    console.log(buttons);
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons; i++) {
        var number = i + 1;
        $(".pagination").append("<li><a class='navigation-number'>"+number+"</a></li>");
        //console.log(number);
    };
    $('.navigation-number').on('click', function() {
        var pageNumber  = $(this).text(); 
        goTo(pageNumber -1);
    });
```

this only results in 4 images on each page, but I wanted 8 on one page

```
    <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <!-- post thumbnail -->
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'img-responsive image')); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- /post thumbnail -->
        <div class="edit-post-link">
            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit 3:

```
<div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
    <!-- post thumbnail -->
                <a href="http://www.q-mediaspot.nl/blog/cinema-4d/cinema-4d-vaas/" title="Cinema 4d Vaas" style="display: none;">
            <img src="http://www.q-mediaspot.nl/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/placeholder1-250x150.jpg" class="img-responsive image wp-post-image" alt="placeholder1">            </a>
            <!-- /post thumbnail -->

    <div class="edit-post-link">
        <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://www.mywebsite.nl/blog/wp-admin/post.php?post=4&amp;action=edit">Edit This</a>    
    </div>
```

Comment: `.portfolio-item a img` selects `img` inside `a` inside `.portfolio-item`. This jQuery selector is interpreted exactly the same as in CSS, so being new to jQuery is no excuse (unless you're also new to CSS).

Comment: Can you post your HTML and say which elements you're trying to select? It's hard to tell what you want from the explanation.

Comment: Selectors operate on HTML, not on PHP.  You're going to want to examine the *actual HTML* of the page.

Comment: It's still unclear which elements you're trying to select. Since the thumbnail `<img>` is inside the `<a>`, why do you need to select them both?

Comment: Well I mean the `<img>` inside `<a>` goes to the post and the other `<?php edit_post_link(); ?>` (this creates a `<a>` too) and both need to disapear when next page is loaded

Answer (score 1):

This

```
$('.portfolio-item').children('a, img')
```

Comment: Neha you're post helped a bit, because it's displaying 8 items now but the edit-post-link is still displaying

Answer (score 0):

```
var $els = $("img.className, a.otherClassName");
```

Comment: I think you mean $("img.className, a.otherClassName")

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$(".portfolio-item a img")
```

Will select `img` elements which are inside of `a` elements which are inside of any element with the `portfolio-item` class.

It *sounds like* you want to select `a` and `img` elements which *themselves* have that class.  Which would be something like this:

```
$("a.portfolio-item, img.portfolio-item")
```

Or, to break it down descriptively (not an actual selector in this case):

```
$("[tag].[class of that tag], [another tag].[class of that tag]")
```

Any tag, any class, however you want to define it.  Specifically note that there is *no space* between the tag and the class in this selector.  That's because *with a space* it means "the second part as a child of the first part" whereas *without a space* it means "the second part as a modifier of the first part".

---

**Edit:** Or, perhaps I misunderstood.  Do you mean that the `a` and `img` tags are themselves *descendants* of some other element of the `portfolio-item` class?  In that case, it would be more like this:

```
$(".portfolio-item a, .portfolio-item img")
```

That is, "all `a` elements which are inside any `.portfolio-item` element, and all `img` elements which are inside any `.portfolio-item` element".

Comment: The question says "both tags have different class names "

Comment: @Barmar: Though it also says "and are in a .portfolio-item class".

Comment: Based on his edit, it looks like it's `<div class=portfolio-item><a><img></a></a></div>`. I'm not sure why he needs to select both `<a>` and `<img>`.

Comment: Barmar the `<img>` inside the `<a>` is for going to the post itself and the other is for editing the post